# Using cell factory in JFXListView ignores JFoenix style

Tags: listview, javafx, kotlin, javafx-8, jfoenix

While using JFoenix control `JFXListView` I am unable to assign the material style to the list if I use a cell factory. How can I use a cell factory and at the same time specify the style for the `JFXListView` control?

Here's my Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

**demoStyle.css** (excerpt from JFoenix demo)

```
.jfx-list-cell-container {
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
}

.jfx-list-cell-container > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: BLACK;
}

.jfx-list-cell:odd:selected > .jfx-rippler > StackPane, .jfx-list-cell:even:selected > .jfx-rippler > StackPane {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

.jfx-list-cell {
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-text-fill: BLACK;
}

.jfx-list-cell:odd, .jfx-list-cell:even {
    -fx-background-color: WHITE;
}

.jfx-list-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.jfx-list-cell .jfx-rippler {
    -jfx-rippler-fill: BLUE;
}

.jfx-list-view {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -jfx-cell-horizontal-margin: 0.0;
    -jfx-cell-vertical-margin: 5.0;
    -jfx-vertical-gap: 10;
    -jfx-expanded: false;
    -fx-pref-width: 200;
}
```

**demoLayout.fxml**

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<HBox
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="<some>.<valid>.<package>.<structure>.DemoController"
        minWidth="Infinity"
        minHeight="Infinity"
>
    <JFXListView fx:id="jfoenixListViewPlain"/>

    <JFXListView fx:id="jfoenixListViewWithCustomCell"/>
</HBox>
```

**Demo.kt**

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.fxml.FXML
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.fxml.Initializable
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import javafx.stage.Stage
import java.net.URL
import java.util.*

data class MyCustomData(val text: String)

class DemoController : Initializable
{
    internal class MyCustomCell : ListCell<MyCustomData>()
    {
        init
        {
            text = null
            contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY
        }

        override fun updateItem(item: MyCustomData?, empty: Boolean)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty)

            graphic =
                    if (empty || item == null)
                    {
                        null
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // In practice this isn't a Label but a Pane with multiple children
                        Label().apply { text = item.text }
                    }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private lateinit var jfoenixListViewPlain: JFXListView<String>

    @FXML
    private lateinit var jfoenixListViewWithCustomCell: JFXListView<MyCustomData>


    override fun initialize(location: URL?, resources: ResourceBundle?)
    {
        val plainList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C")
        jfoenixListViewPlain.items = plainList

        val customItemsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(MyCustomData("A"), MyCustomData("B"), MyCustomData("C"))
        jfoenixListViewWithCustomCell.items = customItemsList
        jfoenixListViewWithCustomCell.setCellFactory { MyCustomCell() }
    }
}

class MainDemoClass : Application()
{
    companion object
    {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>)
        {
            Application.launch(MainDemoClass::class.java, *args)
        }
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun start(stage: Stage)
    {
        val loader = FXMLLoader(javaClass.getResource("/layouts/demoLayout.fxml"))
        val root = loader.load<HBox>()

        with(stage)
        {
            title = "Test's Title"
            scene =
                    Scene(root, 600.0, 600.0, Color.WHITE).apply {
                        with(stylesheets)
                        {
                            add(MainDemoClass::class.java.getResource("/css/jfoenix-design.css").toExternalForm())
                            add(MainDemoClass::class.java.getResource("/css/demoStyle.css").toExternalForm())
                        }
                    }

            isResizable = false
            show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `internal class MyCustomCell : ListCell<MyCustomData>()` on
`internal class MyCustomCell : JFXListCell<MyCustomData>()`